# Proving a simple binomial coefficient expression

Tags: combinatorics

I'm working on this question for homework and am asked to solve the expression using a combinatorial proof. While I understand the basic concept, I'm having trouble working out the solution and would greatly appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Let n and k be integers with n ≥ k + 2 and k ≥ 2.

$$
{n \choose k} = {n - 2 \choose k} + 2 {n - 2 \choose k - 1} + {n - 2 \choose k - 2}
$$

Comment: When you say you understand the basic concept, do you mean you've made some progress? If so, why don't you tell us what you've done?

Comment: @rogerl Apologies, I've worded that poorly. I'm having trouble with how I should approach the question. My understanding of combinatorics is that I'm supposed to divide the original n choose k in terms of the right hand side? The other problems I've done involve taking an element x out of the original n-items, and writing the solution in terms of subsets with and without x.

Comment: The LHS counts ways select $k$ objects from a set of $n$ distinct objects.  Now, what does each term of the RHS count, and why would adding them give the same result?  Hint: the middle term is equal to ${2 \choose 1}{n-2\choose k-1}$

Comment: @SherlockHolmes Oops, didn't catch that. Although it seems to be on hold?

Comment: @GrahamKemp Ah, I see now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Nudge**.  You have probably seen a combinatorial proof of the identity
$$\binom nk=\binom{n-1}k+\binom{n-1}{k-1}\ .$$
Do something very similar.

---

If you have not seen that proof, here it is: we count in two ways the number of possible choices of $k$ items from $n$ different items, where we may not choose the same item more than once and where the order of choices is not important.

Method 1: just choose the items.  The number of choices is $\binom nk$.

Method 2: label one item $X$ and then **either** reject $X$ and choose $k$ items from $n-1$; **or** choose $X$ together with $k-1$ items from $n-1$.  The number of choices is $\binom{n-1}k+\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.